Adding a line to scatter plot series in PowerBi
Is it possible within PowerBi to add a line to each scatter series?
In the example below, this would show the direction of returns over time. This is possible in Excel but I can't emulate in PowerBi.

Here is the Excel example showing what I want to achieve:


This is not possible with native visuals. Look at Deneb

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
